# Number of free faces given n 0-simplexes

Tags: co.combinatorics, simplicial-complexes

Here is my question: How to construct a simplicial complex with $n$ 0-simplex which has the maximum number of free faces? Is there any research topic about this? And is there any relationship between the number of facets and of free faces?

Comment: Can you define "free face"?

Comment: @M.Winter I believe for this question a free face should be face of codimension 1 that contained in exactly one facet.

Comment: A clear definition of  free-face simplexes of arbitrary simplicial complex $S$: a simplex $s^d$ of $\ S\ $ (of arbitrary dimension $d$) is a free-face simplex <=:=> there exists exactly one simplex $\ s^{d+1}\ $ of $\ S\ $ such that $\ s^d\ $ is a face of $\ s^{d+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Delta$ is the $(n-1)$-simplex (which has $n$ vertices), then $\Delta$ is the largest simplicial complex that one can build on top of $n$ vertices, and also every proper face $\tau$ of $\Delta$ is a free face (according to the definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collapse_(topology)), with the entire $(n-1)$-simplex as the unique maximal coface of $\tau$.

Comment: Can you show me how to prove it? We can also split $n$ 0-simplex into several groups and is there any possibility that the total number of free faces is larger than your case?

Comment: If you glue $n-k$ $k$ -simplices along a common facet, then there are $k(n-k)$ free faces.

Comment: Hi Stanley, so should this be the maximum number of free faces? Could you please tell me how to prove it?

Comment: @Sooner, I don't know if this is the maximum (when $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$). I just wanted to point out that the answer of Henry Adams is incorrect.

Comment: Hi all, I'm not sure if I've understood the question correctly or not. If one is looking for only the elementary free faces (those free face pairs $\tau\subseteq\sigma$ where the dimension of $\tau$ is one less than the dimension of $\sigma$), then disregard the idea I propose. However, if one is allowing arbitrary free faces (no dimension requirement), then to my understanding every proper face $\tau$ of the $(n-1)$-simplex $\Delta$ is a free face, giving $2^n-2$ free faces (the minus 2 is to rule out $\tau$ being the emptyset or $\Delta$ itself). Am I interpreting that correctly?

Comment: I guess free face should be **codimension one** face. Under this definition, I want to seek for the maximum number of free faces. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ah, great. When restricting to codimension one free faces, then my idea is definitely not optimal, as (for example) Richard Stanley's idea has more codimension one free faces. I don't know if that is the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious upper bound is $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$ by Sperner's lemma because free faces form an antichain.

An obvious lower bound is $\binom{n-1}{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}$: First take a simplicial complex on $\{1, \dots, n-1\}$ such that its faces are sets of size $\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor$ and their subsets. There is $\binom{n-1}{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}$ maximal faces. Then take the cone over this complex from a vertex $n$. All maximal faces in the former complex are now free in the cone.

This gives approximation with factor of $2$. The upper bound can be achieved for $n=1, 2, 3$ but I am not sure whether there are other values where it can be achieved (= I didn't find any other with a small amount of effort.)

Answer (score 0):

*A warm-up exercise*. Let's consider the homogeneous case of all free-face simplexes $\ s^d\ $ being of the same dimension $\ d.\ $ Then perhaps we want every $\ s^d\ $ being a face of its unique simplex of dimension $\ d+1,\ $ and we want the pair intersections of $\ (d+1)$-dimensional simplexes having dimension always $\ < d,\ $ i.e. having intersections that have at the most $\ d\ $ vertices.

---

Let's start simple with $\ d=1\ $ (case $\ d=0\ $ is trivial). The first interesting series consists of finite projection planes that have $3$-point straight lines. Let $\ P^d\ $ be an $\ n$-dimensional space as this. With $\ P^d,\ $ we associate the $2$-dimensional complex $\ S(P^d),\ $ where the 2-dimensional simplexes will be all straight lines of $\ P^d.\ $ Of course all subsets $\ s\subseteq P^d\ $ such that $\ |s|\le2\ $ are simplexes too. Then the number of vertices is

$$ V\ =\ 2^{d+1}-1 $$

while the number of free-face simplexex (they are 1-simplexex) is:

$$ F\ :=\ \binom V2. $$

we may also consider finite affine spaces $\ A^d\ $ of dimension $\ d,\ $% such that every straight line has 3 points.
Let the respective 2-dimensional simplicial complex $\ Q\ $ have straight lines as its $2$-dimensional simplexes. Then the number of vertices will be

$$ W\ :=\ 3^d $$

and the number of free-face simplexes will be

$$ G\ :=\ \binom W2. $$

*That much for the starters.*

Answer (score 0):

*In the previous answer, I've provided examples of finite simplicial complexes that have an absolutely maximal family of face-free 1-simplexes. Now, let me present the case of free-face 2-simplexes.*

---

---

Let $\ B\ $ be a finite Boolean algebra, say $\ B:=K^d,\ $ where $\ K\ $ is a $2$-element field. Thus $\ B\ $ admits $K$-vector Abelian addition; and
$$ |B|\ =\ 2^d. $$

Consider $3$-dimensional simplicial complex such that $\ s\subseteq B\ $ is a simplex whenever $\ |s|<4;\ $ and on the top of it, $\ 4$-set $\ \{a\ b\ c\ d\}\subseteq B\ $ is
a simplex $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ a+b+c+d=0.$

Then,

**Theorem:** The set of all face-free $\ 2$-simplexes of $\ B\ $ is equal to:

$$ F\ :=\ \binom B3 $$

hence

$$ |F|\ :=\ \binom {|B|}3 $$

is the cardinality of this set of the free-face $2$ simplexes.

*Thank you.*